# Foreign Key reference not populating in intended table

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I'm having a problem referencing a Foreign Key from another table that has already been created with data imported.

```
ALTER TABLE CSEA_BOOK
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_BOOK_CASE_ID FOREIGN KEY (CASE_ID)
    REFERENCES CSEA_CASE(CASE_ID);
```

I can create it just fine but when you

`SELECT *
FROM CSEA_CASE a, CSEA_BOOK b
WHERE a.CASE_ID = b.CASE_ID;`

everything comes back NULL where I know it should contain data.
Am I doing something out of order or Sequence?

Comment: Declaring a foreign key does not change any of the data.  You need an `update` if you want to change the values in fields.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks, but i'm a noob is there a way to perform the update from another table?

Comment: . . Ask another question and provide sample data from the two tables.